# Will googlebot misinterpret my site if I had no spacing between anchor tags?

Tags: html, googlebot, tags, text, googlebot-mobile

Some sections of my website involve displaying a list of photo thumbnails. The source code to that is similar to the following when condensed:

```
<div> <a href="1">1</a> <a href="2">2</a> <a href="2">3</a> </div>
```

I also use stylesheets to format the anchor text so they are boxes with actual pictures in them that people can click on. At this moment, I think google is happy.

What I want to do is convert the above code to this:

```
<div><a href="1">1</a><a href="2">2</a><a href="2">3</a></div>
```

My question then is, if I convert my code and remove the spaces between each anchor tag, would googlebot be confused and believe the text is actually 123 all together when I'm trying to tell it I want the three links together with some spacing via CSS?

I want to shed off some more bytes off my code but at the same time, not confused search engines.

Comment: You should not worry. Removing these extra spaces will do little except for spacing between elements which you can control using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any problems with this at all and [Google **recommends** you remove such space when possible.](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources?hl=en)

> Minification refers to the process of removing unnecessary or
>   redundant data without affecting how the resource is processed by the
>   browser - e.g. code comments and formatting, removing unused code,
>   using shorter variable and function names, and so on.

Comment: I did read about that rule on google, but their page-speed insights tool never complained about it when I have spacing between elements the way I described in my question. I wonder if their tool is buggy

Comment: @Mike The short space they mention between links in `page-speed insights tool` is about design & UX. It simply means that users browsing your website on smaller screen will have problem clicking on these links if they are closer. What you need to do is increase left-right margin on these links in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know a great deal about Search Engine Optimization, but I do know enough about HTML parsing to know that whitespace is mostly ignored to the parser. HTML parsers and SEO parsers ***should*** work in a similar manner. As a rule of thumb I would expect this to be true: If a website's source code is changed and it renders the same, it should rank the same.